# Can I connect to SQL with Node.JS without an external package, or with one universal package?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, node-modules

I know it may be reinventing the wheel to some extent, but I'm creating a package of my own in Node.JS where I would like to keep dependencies to an absolute minimum. This program should connect to SQL (at first, just MySQL, but eventually several different flavors, so if the same answer applies to PostgreSQL, MSSQL, etc. a note about that would be much appreciated) and be able to run queries and such. Is there a way to do so through Node without using an external package like `mysql` or `mssql`?

I do understand that this sounds very impractical, and so I see the need to use "fully debugged open-source software" as the commenter put it. However, requiring a new package for every SQL flavor I extend my program to would be impractical as well. If I must install a package, is there some sort of universal one that I can use for Node.JS (something like PDO in PHP)? If so, what is the basic way of connecting to, say, MySQL?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Both MySQL and SQL Server have fairly protocols they use for connections to applications (like php, Java, and node.js). You are correct: by implementing your own code for either one of those protocols you are indeed reinventing the wheel. But the protocols are so intricate that you may actually be reinventing the pocket watch. **Pro tip** use fully debugged open source software rather than starting over. **Infosec tip** Cybercreeps love it when people don't use fully debugged software for their web apps.

Comment: @O.Jones That's fair. I'm more so looking for the lightest way to do it. Eventually I'll be adding support for more flavors of SQL, so installing a separate package for each of them is going to get insanely impractical fast. I'll edit my question to clarify my intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node has RDBMS-specific packages like [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql), [pg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg), [sqlite3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3), [mssql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql), [ibm_db](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ibm_db), [oracledb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oracledb), ...  all the same except where they aren't.

The php world boasts a [couple of database abstraction layers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.database.php) that can talk to multiple makes and models of RDBMS.  For Java, [JDBC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/) serves the same purpose.

The [npm ladc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ladc) package is a similar project for nodejs; it uses the existing packages for connecting to databases. It seems to be in an early version and not heavily used, according to its npm page.

[Sequelize](https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/v3/) is an object-relational database abstraction above some RDBMSs.  If you are able to use an object-relational model for your data, it's probably a good choice. If you're using lots of pure SQL, [ladc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ladc) might make sense.

It seems as if you're blazing a trail with your project.

Comment: Makes sense. The eventual goal of this project is a semi-framework (bit of a new concept) that would sport some query builder like Laravel does in PHP. I guess there are a few ways around this issue, so I can do for now. I'm just worried that it'll get very impractical. I took a look at ladc and it still requires separate packages. I'm  not necessarily worried about how my program accesses the databases (though a unified abstraction layer would be nice), but more so how the framework users will then need to install a bunch of packages that won't be used.

Comment: The individual packages are open source; it might be possible to repackage the contents.If you'd consider a collaborator on this project of yours, please let me know.